# Iterate over columns with NAs to create percentile variables with dplyr and data.table

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I need quite a simple thing. To iterate over columns of a dataset to create percentil versions of said columns. I tried with dplyr and data.table but none seem to do what I need. Particulary, I need to exclude de NA values when creating the percentile versions of the columns.

Reproducible example below:

```
values<-c(19,
    6,
    27,
    63,
    50,
    59,
    97,
    89,
    NA,
    9,
    31,
    58,
    83,
    2,
    1,
    31,
    3,
    1,
    27,
    40,
    32,
    42,
    99,
    NA,
    12,
    16,
    23,
    98,
    44,
    25,
    13,
    70,
    64,
    NA,
    37,
    75,
    73,
    59,
    21,
    3,
    76,
    43,
    6,
    96,
    55,
    48,
    70,
    90,
    18,
    58,
    22,
    19,
    26,
    49,
    59,
    94,
    31,
    45,
    20,
    8,
    26,
    56,
    7,
    11,
    98,
    50,
    41,
    38,
    86,
    0,
    37,
    NA,
    40,
    7,
    88,
    38,
    41,
    41,
    19,
    34,
    21,
    64,
    87,
    22,
    54,
    39,
    75,
    72,
    91,
    78)

values2<- c(98,
            60,
            9,
            98,
            NA,
            88,
            NA,
            54,
            92,
            90,
            NA,
            83,
            92,
            65,
            44,
            NA,
            98,
            40,
            26,
            40,
            54,
            56,
            15,
            90,
            15,
            63,
            57,
            NA,
            85,
            69,
            73,
            43,
            24,
            27,
            82,
            75,
            29,
            98,
            29,
            5,
            91,
            88,
            28,
            12,
            53,
            NA,
            2,
            42,
            86,
            2,
            78,
            20,
            50,
            73,
            77,
            NA,
            4,
            39,
            90,
            NA,
            29,
            14,
            98,
            88,
            77,
            79,
            30,
            9,
            74,
            93,
            NA,
            16,
            27,
            16,
            18,
            40,
            NA,
            2,
            66,
            71,
            82,
            10,
            62,
            84,
            25,
            NA,
            15,
            12,
            85,
            50)


  groups<-c(1,
1,
1,
1,
1,
1,
1,
1,
1,
1,
1,
1,
1,
1,
1,
1,
1,
1,
1,
1,
1,
1,
1,
1,
1,
1,
1,
1,
2,
2,
2,
2,
2,
2,
2,
2,
2,
2,
2,
2,
2,
2,
2,
2,
2,
2,
2,
2,
2,
2,
2,
2,
2,
2,
2,
2,
2,
2,
2,
2,
2,
2,
2,
2,
2,
2,
2,
2,
2,
2,
2,
2,
2,
2,
2,
2,
2,
2,
2,
2,
2,
2,
2,
2,
2,
2,
2,
2,
2,
2)

df<-as.data.frame(cbind(groups,values,values2))


library(dplyr)

for (i in c("values","values2")) {
    df<-df %>%
      group_by(groups) %>% 
      mutate(!!sym(paste( i,"_percentile", sep="")) := percent_rank(na.omit(i)))
  }


for (i in c("values","values2")) {
  df<-df %>%
    group_by(groups) %>% 
    mutate(!!sym(paste( i,"_percentile", sep="")) := rank(i)/length(i) )
}

library(data.table)

df<- as.data.table(df)

for (i in c("values","values2")) {
  df[,  paste(i,"_percentile",sep="")  := rank(get(i))/length( get(i)), by = groups ]

}


for (i in c("values","values2")) {
  df[!is.na(i),  paste(i,"_percentile",sep="")  := rank(get(i))/length( get(i)), by = groups ]

}
```

Comment: i think you are missing a `get` in your last line of code: `df[!is.na(get(i)),  paste0(i,"_percentile") := frank(get(i)) / .N, groups]`

Answer (score 1):

An option is `mutate_at`.  After grouping by 'groups', use `mutate_at` to loop over the columns that `starts_with` ('values') as column name, `replace`, the values where the values are not NA with the `percent_rank` of the non-NA elements

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   group_by(groups) %>%
   mutate_at(vars(starts_with('values')), 
         list(percentile = ~ replace(., !is.na(.), percent_rank(.[!is.na(.)]))))
```

---

Or with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
nm1 <- paste(names(df1)[2:3], "_percentile")
setDT(df)[, (nm1) := lapply(.SD, function(x) replace(x, !is.na(x), 
      frank(x[!is.na(x)])/sum(!is.na(x)))), .SDcols = 2:3, by = groups]
```

Comment: Thanks, this gets me close. However, I just tried it with my *large* dataset and just got all NaNs with both methods in one seemingly normal variable. Also, shouldn't this return "1" for the highest value for each group, instead of 0.9x? The two methods return (slightly) different values

Answer (score 0):

My `tidyverse` answer has the same structure as @akrun's -- using `mutate_at` to add multiple columns, `starts_with` to select the columns. A few things worth pointing out with the more minimal example:

1. The `percent_rank` function already removes NA's when it calculates, so you don't have to do the additional work to filter them out of the calc.
2. There is one degenerate case where there's only one actual measure. (In my case, it's group "b"). `percent_rank` can return a NaN value there because it's scaling the `min_rank`. Inside the direct `mutate_at`, that issue seems to be avoided. (It's unclear what value that should be assigned to in your case).
3. There's another sort-of degenerate case when there's a tie. In group "a", I have a tie for first place, and the `percent_rank`'s are accordingly not 1.0.

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- tribble(
  ~groups, ~values1, ~values2,
  "a", 1, 10,
  "a", 2, 10,
  "a", NA, 8,
  "a", 3, 9,
  "a", 4, 7,
  "b", NA, 10,
  "b", 2, NA,
  "b", NA, 8
)

df %>%
  group_by(groups) %>%
  mutate_at(
    vars(starts_with("values")),
    list(percentile = ~ percent_rank(.))) 
#> # A tibble: 8 x 5
#> # Groups:   groups [2]
#>   groups values1 values2 values1_percentile values2_percentile
#>   <chr>    <dbl>   <dbl>              <dbl>              <dbl>
#> 1 a            1      10              0                   0.75
#> 2 a            2      10              0.333               0.75
#> 3 a           NA       8             NA                   0.25
#> 4 a            3       9              0.667               0.5 
#> 5 a            4       7              1                   0   
#> 6 b           NA      10             NA                   1   
#> 7 b            2      NA              0                  NA   
#> 8 b           NA       8             NA                   0
```